# Create Appointment with Multiple Recipients in Dynamics

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm

I need to create an appointment with multiple recipients in MS Dynamics. Note that I do not actually want to save the appointment...that should only happen once the user clicks save. I just want to display the form with multiple recipients already added.

If I use the URL for the appointment form:

```
/activities/appointment/edit.aspx
```

I can specify a partyId url parameter which is the Dynamics GUID for the person I want to add to the recipients....but what if I want to add multiple recipients? Is there a way to do this with URL parameters?

If not, is there a way to programatically add recipients in the form's OnLoad javascript? That is, are there any JavaScript API hooks for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you won't be able to set more than one party using CRM's partyid/partyidname query string parameters.

Yes, there are onload hooks.  [Lookup scripting reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189833.aspx).   In the second example you'll see how they set a lookup in script.

```
// Add the object to the array.
lookupData[0] = lookupItem;
```

You'd just have multiple of these for each of your recipients/resources.

```
// Add the object to the array.
lookupData[0] = lookupItem;
lookupData[1] = lookupItem2;
lookupData[2] = lookupItem3;
```

Then its just a matter of how you pass the data to the appointment edit form.  You can't add random query string parameters (CRM validates all query string parameters are in a set of known parameters).  So you have to do something else to send the data.  A couple options...

- Put the GUIDs/Names in a cookie in the opening page and parse in the onload (CRM already requires cookies).
- Create a string attribute and put it on the appointment form.  Hide it using javascript (display:none).  That part is "unsupported", but you're not going to want a visible attribute containing a bunch of GUIDs.  You'll be able to google hiding a form field.  Use this attribute to pass/validate your data by query string.  Parse the attribute at runtime.

Hope it helps...